# Macro to loop through cells of similar value/product and send that range of email

Tags: vba, excel, email

I have a created a macro for my spreadsheet which can sent out emails successfully.

However, it can only send e-mails of each individual part numbers which are over the due date. Which means if I have 100 over the due date part numbers, there will be 100 emails being sent out.

I would like my macro to send the email by a range of cells which are of similar product (eg. printer) and are over the due date. There can be other products like laptop, camera, webcam as well. I need to do this as i don't want to spam the receiver's inbox.

How do I do that?

```
Sub LabelArtworkRelease()

    Dim OutApp As Object
    Dim Message1 As Object
    Dim cell As Range
    Dim emailBody As String
    Dim Signature As String

    'GET DEFAULT EMAIL SIGNATURE
    Signature = Environ("appdata") & "\Microsoft\Signatures\"
    If Dir(Signature, vbDirectory) <> vbNullString Then
        Signature = Signature & Dir$(Signature & "*.htm")
    Else:
        Signature = ""
    End If
    Signature = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject").GetFile(Signature).OpenAsTextStream(1, -2).ReadAll
    'End

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    'Create a new Outlook session
    Set appOutlook = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")

    On Error GoTo cleanup

            'Declare header variables
            partnumber = Range("A3").Value
            productfamily = Range("B3").Value
            desc = Range("C3").Value
            artworkactual = Range("F3").Value
            artworkexpected = Range("G3").Value
            remark = Range("L3").Value

            On Error Resume Next

            'if artwork actual date is later than artwork expected date
            For Each cell In Columns("B").Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants)
            If Cells(cell.Row, "G").Value < Cells(cell.Row, "F").Value And Cells(cell.Row, "L").Value = "Incomplete" Then

            'Create a new message
            Set Message1 = appOutlook.CreateItem(olMailItem)


            'Create default message
            emailBody = "<Font face=Calibri>Hi " & Cells(cell.Row, "D").Value & " , <p>" _
                            & "Please be reminded that the following part numbers - is/are over the expected artwork release date. <p> Kindly act on the following item(s): <br> " _
                            & "<table border=1><tr><th>" _
                            & partnumber & "</th>" _
                            & "<th>" & productfamily & "</th>" _
                            & "<th>" & desc & "</th>" _
                            & "<th>" & artworkactual & "</th>" _
                            & "<th>" & artworkexpected & "</th>" _
                            & "<th>" & remark & "</th>" _
                            & "<tr>" _
                            & "<td>" & Cells(cell.Row, "A").Value & "</td>" _
                            & "<td>" & Cells(cell.Row, "B").Value & "</td>" _
                            & "<td>" & Cells(cell.Row, "C").Value & "</td>" _
                            & "<td>" & Cells(cell.Row, "F").Value & "</td>" _
                            & "<td>" & Cells(cell.Row, "G").Value & "</td>" _
                            & "<td>" & Cells(cell.Row, "L").Value & "</td></tr></table><br /></font>" & Signature



            With Message1
                .to = "email@email.com"
                .CC = Cells(cell.Row, "N") & ";" & Cells(cell.Row, "O")
                .Subject = "Reminder for Label Artwork Tracking (Artwork Expected Date) - Product Family (" & Cells(cell.Row, "B").Value & ")"
                .HTMLBody = emailBody



                .Send
                End With




            On Error GoTo 0
            Set OutMail = Nothing
    End If
    Next cell

cleanup:
    Set OutApp = Nothing
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

First you can alphabetically sort the column with Product names and then within if statement you put a condition like:

```
If Cells(cell.Row, "Product name column").Value <> Cells(cell.Row + 1, "Product name column").Value then
```

So macro runs the rest of the code only after reaching the last item with the same name.

Comment: Thank you for your reply :) i have input the code and i did receive emails for different products i have input in my spreadsheet. But the thing is, i didn't receive the e-mail for example: printers' shipment due date are overdue (note: i can have several printers which are overdue). I only received 1 row of the overdue date printer. Can you solve this for me?

Comment: Can i also add in AND condition inside my IF condition? as i want to compare 2 different cell dates so as to know which item is overdue. I tried adding in AND but the code isn't working.

Comment: @jasmine but you already have AND condition within one of your IFs:

`If Cells(cell.Row, "G").Value < Cells(cell.Row, "F").Value And Cells(cell.Row, "L").Value = "Incomplete" Then`
Does it work?

Comment: nope it does not run at all unfortunately. :( my code goes like this now: If Cells(cell.Row, "B").Value <> Cells(cell.Row + 1, "B").Value And Cells(cell.Row, "G").Value < Cells(cell.Row, "F").Value And Cells(cell.Row, "L").Value = "Incomplete" Then

Comment: Where does it stop and what is it saying?

Comment: it didn't show me any error or to debug any row. It just doesn't run :(